# How to do batching without UBOs?

Tags: optimization, 3d, webgl

I'm trying to implement batching for a WebGL renderer which is struggling with lots of small objects due to too many draw calls. What I thought is I'd batch them all by the kind of shader they use, then draw a few at a time, uploading material parameters and the model matrix for each object once in uniforms.

My problem is that the uniform size limits for non-UBO uniforms are extremely low, as in 256 floats low at a minimum. If my material uses, say, 8 floats, and if you factor in the model matrix, I barely have enough uniforms to draw 10 models in a single batch, which isn't really going to be enough.

Is there any hope to make this work without UBOs? Are textures an option? How are people doing batching without WebGL2 UBOs?

More details: I have no skinning or complex animations, I just have some shaders (diffuse, cook-torrance, whatever) and each model has different material settings for each shader, e.g. color, roughness, index of refraction which can be changed dynamically by the user (so it's not realistic to bake them into the vertex array because we have some high poly data, also users can switch shaders and not all shaders have the same number of parameters) as well as material maps obviously. The geometry itself is static and just has a linear transform on each model. For the most part all meshes are different so geometry instancing won't help a whole lot, but I can look at that later.

Thanks

Comment: Textures are certainly a common solution to getting more data in than you can with just uniforms. For example three.js uses textures to pass in bone matrices for skinning. See [webgl skinning example with data in textures here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-skinning.html). It would be easier to help if you explained exactly what you're trying to do. Are you trying to draw 1000s of the same shape, different shapes, what's different about each instance, etc....

Comment: @gman Thanks, I've added some more detail to the question.

Comment: I'd consider adding an id per model so for every vertex in model #0 put a 0, for every vertex in model #1 put a 1, etc. Then I could use that model id to index stuff in a texture. The easiest would be model id chooses the row of a texture and then all the data for that model can be pulled out of that row. Test and see if it's fast enough `float modelOffset = (modelId + .5) / textureHeight; vec4 color = texture2D(perModelData, vec2(COLOR_OFFSET, modelOffset)); vec4 roughnessIndexOfRefaction = texture(2D, perModelData, vec2(MATERIAL_OFFSET, modelOffset);` etc...

Comment: Also though, I'm not at all clear on what you mean by batching with UBOs. UBOs do not increase the number of uniforms available nor do they help batching. All they do is theoretically make it faster to update uniforms.

Comment: @gman I really like the idea of the texture, also only a subrange of it can be updated if only a single model changes which is the normal use case so updates should be quite fast. I'll give it a try, maybe you can post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that this is actually faster than lots of draw calls but here is drawing 4 models with a single draw call

It works by adding an id per model. So, for every vertex in model #0 put a 0, for every vertex in model #1 put a 1, etc.

Then it uses model id to index stuff in a texture. The easiest would be model id chooses the row of a texture and then all the data for that model can be pulled out of that row.

For WebGL1

```
attribute float modelId;

...

#define TEXTURE_WIDTH ??
#define COLOR_OFFSET    ((0.0 + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
#define MATERIAL_OFFSET ((1.0 + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)

float modelOffset = (modelId + .5) / textureHeight;
vec4 color = texture2D(perModelData, vec2(COLOR_OFFSET, modelOffset));
vec4 roughnessIndexOfRefaction = texture2D(perModelData, 
                                           vec2(MATERIAL_OFFSET, modelOffset));
```

etc..

As long as you are not drawing more than `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)` models it will work. If you have more than that either use more draw calls or change the texture coordinate calculations so there's more than one model per row

In WebGL2 you'd change the code to use `texelFetch` and unsigned integers

```
in uint modelId;

...

#define COLOR_OFFSET    0
#define MATERIAL_OFFSET 1

vec4 color = texelFetch(perModelData, uvec2(COLOR_OFFSET, modelId));
vec4 roughnessIndexOfRefaction = texelFetch(perModelData, 
                                            uvec2(MATERIAL_OFFSET, modelId));
```

example of 4 models drawn with 1 draw call. For each model the model matrix and color are stored in the texture.

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const v3 = twgl.v3;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const ext = gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
if (!ext) {
  alert('need OES_texture_float');
}

const COMMON_STUFF = `
#define TEXTURE_WIDTH 5.0
#define MATRIX_ROW_0_OFFSET ((0. + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
#define MATRIX_ROW_1_OFFSET ((1. + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
#define MATRIX_ROW_2_OFFSET ((2. + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
#define MATRIX_ROW_3_OFFSET ((3. + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
#define COLOR_OFFSET        ((4. + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
`;

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute float modelId;

uniform float textureHeight;
uniform sampler2D perModelDataTexture;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying float v_modelId;

${COMMON_STUFF}

void main() {
  v_modelId = modelId;  // pass to fragment shader

  float modelOffset = (modelId + 0.5) / textureHeight;

  // note: in WebGL2 better to use texelFetch
  mat4 model = mat4(
    texture2D(perModelDataTexture, vec2(MATRIX_ROW_0_OFFSET, modelOffset)),
    texture2D(perModelDataTexture, vec2(MATRIX_ROW_1_OFFSET, modelOffset)),
    texture2D(perModelDataTexture, vec2(MATRIX_ROW_2_OFFSET, modelOffset)),
    texture2D(perModelDataTexture, vec2(MATRIX_ROW_3_OFFSET, modelOffset)));
  
  gl_Position = projection * view * model * position;
  v_normal = mat3(view) * mat3(model) * normal;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying float v_modelId;

uniform float textureHeight;
uniform sampler2D perModelDataTexture;
uniform vec3 lightDirection;

${COMMON_STUFF}

void main() {
  float modelOffset = (v_modelId + 0.5) / textureHeight;

  vec4 color = texture2D(perModelDataTexture, vec2(COLOR_OFFSET, modelOffset));
  
  float l = dot(lightDirection, normalize(v_normal)) * .5 + .5;
  
  gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb * l, color.a);
}
`;

// compile shader, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// make some vertex data
const modelVerts = [
  twgl.primitives.createSphereVertices(1, 6, 4),
  twgl.primitives.createCubeVertices(1, 1, 1),
  twgl.primitives.createCylinderVertices(1, 1, 10, 1),
  twgl.primitives.createTorusVertices(1, .2, 16, 8),
];
// merge all the vertices into one
const arrays = twgl.primitives.concatVertices(modelVerts);
// fill an array so each vertex of each model has a modelId
const modelIds = new Uint16Array(arrays.position.length / 3);
let offset = 0;
modelVerts.forEach((verts, modelId) => {
  const end = offset + verts.position.length / 3;
  while(offset < end) {
    modelIds[offset++] = modelId;
  }
});
arrays.modelId = { numComponents: 1, data: modelIds };
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

const numModels = modelVerts.length;
const tex = gl.createTexture();
const textureWidth = 5; // 4x4 matrix, 4x1 color
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, textureWidth, numModels, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// this data is for the texture, one row per model
// first 4 pixels are the model matrix, 5 pixel is the color
const perModelData = new Float32Array(textureWidth * numModels * 4);
const stride = textureWidth * 4;
const modelOffset = 0;
const colorOffset = 16;

// set the colors at init time
for (let modelId = 0; modelId < numModels; ++modelId) {
  perModelData.set([r(), r(), r(), 1], modelId * stride + colorOffset);
}

function r() {
  return Math.random();
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

  const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 20;
  const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
  
  const eye = [0, 0, 10];
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];
  const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);

  // set the matrix for each model in the texture data
  const mat = m4.identity();
  for (let modelId = 0; modelId < numModels; ++modelId) {
    const t = time * (modelId + 1) * 0.3;
    m4.identity(mat);
    m4.rotateX(mat, t, mat);
    m4.rotateY(mat, t, mat);
    m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, Math.sin(t * 1.1) * 4], mat);
    m4.rotateZ(mat, t, mat);
    
    perModelData.set(mat, modelId * stride + modelOffset);
  }
  
  // upload the texture data
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, textureWidth, numModels, 
                   gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, perModelData);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    lightDirection: v3.normalize([1, 2, 3]),
    perModelDataTexture: tex,
    textureHeight: numModels,
    projection,
    view,
  });  
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Here's 2000 models in one draw call

https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/g2tcadho/