# In WebGL - when instancing geometry, is it possible to pass per-vertex attribute information for each instance?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I am trying to recreate through raw WebGL [the following three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=video#webgl_materials_video) with instanced geometry; though, after testing it looks like I may just have to draw multiple meshes like in the sample but I thought I would ask here first to double check.

The question now is essentially - is it possible to pass per-vertex data for each instance of the geometry that gets rendered?

Hopefully that makes sense but if it doesn't -

- The geometry I'm rendering has 4 vertices.
- For each instance of the geometry - I need to assign uv coords to each vertex of each instance of the geometry
- it seems that setting a stride or offset does not appear to work.

Basically what is happening now is given the current data which looks something like

```
[s1,t1,s2,t2,s3,t3,s4,t4,s1,t1,s2,t2,s3,t3,s4,t4] // enough uvs for 2 instances, each s and t value makes up 1 uv coord for 1 vertex
```

Instead of data being read and assigned in blocks like this

```
      // instance 1            // instance 2
[[s1,t1,s2,t2,s3,t3,s4,t4], [s1,t1,s2,t2,s3,t3,s4,t4]]

// Each s and t forms 1 uv coord for 1 vertex
```

Data appears to be instead being read like this

```
  [s1,t1,s2,t2,s3,t3,s4,t4,s1,t1,s2,t2,s3,t3,s4,t4]
  // Each s and t pair is assigned to every vertex of each instance
```

Is it at all possible to get things working like in the second block? If not that's fine but thought I ought to ask.

Comment: "*The geometry I'm rendering has 4 vertices.*" OK, let me stop you right there. Don't do instancing just to render quads. Just repeat the position data; you'll almost certainly be better off, performance-wise.

Comment: Agree with what Nicol said. It's faster to repeat the data than to use instancing so the less vertices per instance the better it is to just repeat the data.

Comment: ah got it - thanks for the tip Nicol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by

> is it possible to pass per-vertex data for each instance of the geometry that gets rendered?

If you mean via attributes then the answer is no. You can get data per vertex or data per instance but not data per vertex per instance.

But you also get 2 extra inputs, `gl_VertexID` and `gl_InstanceID` (in WebGL2) or you can add your own which you could use to either compute UVs or use to look up data in a texture to effectively achieve your desired result.

For example let's say you have 20x10 cubes. You could do something like

```
attribute vec4 position;    // 36 cube positions
attribute vec2 uv;          // 36 cube UVs
attribute float instanceId; // 1 per instance

uniform float cubesAcross;  // set to 20
uniform float cubesDown;    // set to 10

varying v_uv;

void main() {
  float cubeX = mod(instanceId, cubesAcross);
  float cubeY = floor(instanceId / cubesAcross);

  v_vu = (vec2(cubeX, cubeY) + uv) / vec2(cubesAcross, cubesDown);

  gl_Position = ...whatever you were doing for position before...
}
```

example:

```js
"use strict";

function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  const ext = gl.getExtension('ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  if (!ext) {
    return alert('need ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  }
  twgl.addExtensionsToContext(gl);
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;
  attribute mat4 matrix;
  attribute float instanceId;

  uniform float cubesAcross;  // set to 20
  uniform float cubesDown;    // set to 10

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    gl_Position = matrix * position;
    
    float cubeX = mod(instanceId, cubesAcross);
    float cubeY = floor(instanceId / cubesAcross);

    v_texcoord = (vec2(cubeX, cubeY) + texcoord) / vec2(cubesAcross, cubesDown);
  }
  `;

  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_texcoord, 0, 1);
  }
  `;

  // compile shaders, link, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  const cubesAcross = 20;
  const cubesDown = 10;
  const numCubes = cubesAcross * cubesDown;
  // matrix per instance
  const matrixData = new Float32Array(16 * numCubes);
  const matrices = [];
  const instanceIds = new Float32Array(numCubes);
  for (let i = 0; i < numCubes; ++i) {
    instanceIds[i] = i;
    // make a typedarray view for each matrix
    matrices.push(matrixData.subarray(i * 16, (i + 1) * 16));
  }

  const arrays = {
    position: [
       1,  1, -1, 
       1,  1,  1, 
       1, -1,  1,
       1, -1, -1,
       
      -1,  1,  1,
      -1,  1, -1,
      -1, -1, -1,
      -1, -1,  1, 
      
      -1,  1,  1, 
       1,  1,  1, 
       1,  1, -1,
      -1,  1, -1,
      
      -1, -1, -1,
       1, -1, -1,
       1, -1,  1,
      -1, -1,  1,
      
       1,  1,  1,
      -1,  1,  1,
      -1, -1,  1,
       1, -1,  1,
       
      -1,  1, -1,
       1,  1, -1,
       1, -1, -1,
      -1, -1, -1,
    ],
    texcoord: [
      1, 0,
      0, 0,
      0, 1,
      1, 1,
      
      1, 0,
      0, 0,
      0, 1,
      1, 1,
      
      0, 1,
      1, 1,
      1, 0,
      0, 0,
      
      0, 1,
      1, 1,
      1, 0,
      0, 0,
      
      1, 1,
      0, 1,
      0, 0,
      1, 0,
      
      1, 0,
      0, 0,
      0, 1,
      1, 1,
    ],
    indices: [
       0,  1,  2,  0,  2,  3,
       4,  5,  6,  4,  6,  7,
       8,  9, 10,  8, 10, 11,
      12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15,
      16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19,
      20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23,
    ],
    instanceId: { numComponents: 1, data: instanceIds, divisor: 1 },
    matrix: { numComponents: 16, data: matrices, divisor: 1 },
  };
  // create buffers, upload data (gl.bufferData)
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    const fov = 30 * Math.PI / 180;
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const zNear = 0.5;
    const zFar = 100;
    const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
    const eye = [1, 24, 76];
    const target = [18, 10, 0];
    const up = [0, 1, 0];

    const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
    const view = m4.inverse(camera);
    const viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
    
    // update the instance for each matrix
    const spacing = 2.5 + Math.sin(time) * .5;
    let i = 0;
    for (let y = 0; y < cubesDown; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < cubesAcross; ++x) {
        const matrix = matrices[i++];
        m4.translate(viewProjection, [
          x * spacing,
          y * spacing,
          0,
        ], matrix);
      }
    }

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer, ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      cubesAcross,
      cubesDown,
    });
    
    // upload instance matrices to buffer
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferInfo.attribs.matrix.buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, matrixData, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    ext.drawElementsInstancedANGLE(
      gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0,  numCubes);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

If you actually want unique per vertex per instance data then put it in a texture and pass in a vertexId as well. Then use both vertexId and instanceId to compute a texture coordinate

```
  attribute float instanceId;
  attribute float vertexId;

  uniform sampler2D dataTexture;
  uniform vec2 dataTextureSize;

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {

    // each row is for an instance, each texel
    // per vertex. Of course if you want more data
    // per vertex then multiply vertexId by the number of
    // vec4s of data you need. If you need more instances
    // then compute a more complex offset based off instanceId
    vec2 uv = (vec2(vertexId, instanceId) + .5) / dataTextureSize;
    vec4 data = texture2D(dataTexture, uv);

    v_texcoord = data.xy;
```

```js
"use strict";

function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  const ext1 = gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
  if (!ext1) {
    return alert('need OES_texture_float');
  }
  const ext = gl.getExtension('ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  if (!ext) {
    return alert('need ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
  }
  twgl.addExtensionsToContext(gl);
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute mat4 matrix;
  attribute float instanceId;
  attribute float vertexId;
  
  uniform sampler2D dataTexture;
  uniform vec2 dataTextureSize;

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    gl_Position = matrix * position;

    // each row is for an instance, each texel
    // per vertex. Of course if you want more data
    // per vertex then multiply vertexId by the number of
    // vec4s of data you need. If you need more instances
    // then compute a more complex offset based off instanceId
    vec2 uv = (vec2(vertexId, instanceId) + .5) / dataTextureSize;
    vec4 data = texture2D(dataTexture, uv);

    v_texcoord = data.xy;
  }
  `;

  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_texcoord, 0, 1);
  }
  `;

  // compile shaders, link, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  const cubesAcross = 20;
  const cubesDown = 10;
  const numCubes = cubesAcross * cubesDown;
  // matrix per instance
  const matrixData = new Float32Array(16 * numCubes);
  const matrices = [];
  const instanceIds = new Float32Array(numCubes);
  for (let i = 0; i < numCubes; ++i) {
    instanceIds[i] = i;
    // make a typedarray view for each matrix
    matrices.push(matrixData.subarray(i * 16, (i + 1) * 16));
  }

  const arrays = {
    position: [
       1,  1, -1, 
       1,  1,  1, 
       1, -1,  1,
       1, -1, -1,
       
      -1,  1,  1,
      -1,  1, -1,
      -1, -1, -1,
      -1, -1,  1, 
      
      -1,  1,  1, 
       1,  1,  1, 
       1,  1, -1,
      -1,  1, -1,
      
      -1, -1, -1,
       1, -1, -1,
       1, -1,  1,
      -1, -1,  1,
      
       1,  1,  1,
      -1,  1,  1,
      -1, -1,  1,
       1, -1,  1,
       
      -1,  1, -1,
       1,  1, -1,
       1, -1, -1,
      -1, -1, -1,
    ],
    vertexId: {
      numComponents: 1,
      data: [
         0,  1,  2,  3,
         4,  5,  6,  7,
         8,  9, 10, 11,
        12, 13, 14, 15,
        16, 17, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 21, 23,
      ],
    },
    indices: [
       0,  1,  2,  0,  2,  3,
       4,  5,  6,  4,  6,  7,
       8,  9, 10,  8, 10, 11,
      12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15,
      16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19,
      20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23,
    ],
    instanceId: { numComponents: 1, data: instanceIds, divisor: 1 },
    matrix: { numComponents: 16, data: matrices, divisor: 1 },
  };
  // create buffers, upload data (gl.bufferData)
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

  // put UV data in texture
  const uvs = [];
  for (let y = 0; y < cubesDown; ++y) {
    const v0 = (y    ) / cubesDown;
    const v1 = (y + 1) / cubesDown;
    for (let x = 0; x < cubesAcross; ++x) {
      const u0 = (x    ) / cubesAcross;
      const u1 = (x + 1) / cubesAcross;
      uvs.push(u0, v0, 0, 0, u1, v0, 0, 0, u0, v1, 0, 0, u1, v1, 0, 0);
      uvs.push(u0, v0, 0, 0, u1, v0, 0, 0, u0, v1, 0, 0, u1, v1, 0, 0);
      uvs.push(u0, v0, 0, 0, u1, v0, 0, 0, u0, v1, 0, 0, u1, v1, 0, 0);
      uvs.push(u0, v0, 0, 0, u1, v0, 0, 0, u0, v1, 0, 0, u1, v1, 0, 0);
      uvs.push(u0, v0, 0, 0, u1, v0, 0, 0, u0, v1, 0, 0, u1, v1, 0, 0);
      uvs.push(u0, v0, 0, 0, u1, v0, 0, 0, u0, v1, 0, 0, u1, v1, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  
  const texWidth = 24; // width = 24 vertices * 1 texel per
  const texHeight = numCubes; // height = numInstances
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    0,  // level
    gl.RGBA,
    texWidth,
    texHeight,
    0,  // border
    gl.RGBA,
    gl.FLOAT,
    new Float32Array(uvs));


  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    const fov = 30 * Math.PI / 180;
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const zNear = 0.5;
    const zFar = 100;
    const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
    const eye = [1, 24, 76];
    const target = [18, 10, 0];
    const up = [0, 1, 0];

    const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
    const view = m4.inverse(camera);
    const viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
    
    // update the instance for each matrix
    const spacing = 2.5 + Math.sin(time) * .5;
    let i = 0;
    for (let y = 0; y < cubesDown; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < cubesAcross; ++x) {
        const matrix = matrices[i++];
        m4.translate(viewProjection, [
          x * spacing,
          y * spacing,
          0,
        ], matrix);
      }
    }

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer, ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      dataTexture: tex,
      dataTextureSize: [texWidth, texHeight],
    });
    
    // upload instance matrices to buffer
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferInfo.attribs.matrix.buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, matrixData, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    ext.drawElementsInstancedANGLE(
      gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0,  numCubes);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54720138/128511)

Comment: Thanks for the help and many thanks for the detailed sample! Figured it would have to end up something along these lines if I didn't just re-render things.